# SQL query - two group bys on intermediate result in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a fairly long and complex query that ends up producing a result like this:

```
item_id  |  shop_id   |   sold
   5           3            0
   5           3            1
   5           3            1
   8           4            0
   8           6            1
   8           9            0
```

I need to then to somehow do a `SELECT item_id, COUNT(DISTINCT (shop_id)) FROM tableAbove GROUP BY item_id` to get:

```
    item_id   | number of shops that sell/have sold item
       5                1
       8                3
```

However, I also need for each item the number of shops that have successfully sold it, So something like this:

```
    item_id    |  number of shops that have sold item
       5                    1
       8                    1
```

Does anyone know how I can put them bother together in a query to give

```
    item_id    |  shops that sell item  |number of shops that have sold item
       5                     1                         1
       8                     3                         1
```

Comment: Is the sold column True/False, or Quantity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  item_id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT shop_id),
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sold = 1 THEN shop_id END)
FROM    my_query
GROUP BY
        item_id
```